# Using Limit Comparison Test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+\ln(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am told to use the Limit Comparison Test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+ \ln(n)}$. The question says to "discuss the convergence" of it, but after using the test I am getting something otherwise.

**My work**:

$a_n = \frac{1}{n+ \ln(n)}$

$b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ which I know is a harmonic series so it will diverge.

I evaluated the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n+\ln(n)}}{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$

Knowing that my $c$ value is $1$, I know that because $b_n$ diverges so should $a_n$.

--

Am I going wrong anywhere? And if so, where?

Comment: That’s fine. In this context ‘discuss the convergence’ basically means ‘determine whether it converges or not and explain your reasoning’.

Comment: Why not just note that $\log(n)<n$ so that $\frac1{n+\log(n)}>\frac1{2n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, and I guess the question was to ask you whether the series converges or diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of curiosity, I propose another way to approach it.

Since $\ln(n) < n$ for every $n\geq 1$, one has that $n + \ln(n) < 2n$, that is to say
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n+\ln(n)} > \frac{1}{2n}
\end{align*}

Since the given harmonic series on the RHS diverges, the given series diverges as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.
If you know some asymptotic analysis, you can make it shorter: 
as it is known from high school that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln n}n=0$, it means in terms of asymptotic analysis, that $\ln n=0(n)$, so
$$n+\ln n\sim_\infty n,\quad\text{whence }\frac1{n+\ln n}\sim_\infty \frac 1n.$$
Now, a theorem asserts that two series with equivalent positive terms both converge or both diverge.

Comment: I think that is exactly what OP did 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: The OP did it, but not exactly so short. I wanted to point out the simplifications asymptotic analysis can bring by removing the irrelevant computational details.